# View apache error log in real time

Tags: php, apache

I am building a PHP app using mod_php in apache.
However during the course of development I will have syntax errors in the code (of course).

When I load the page with errors on I get a 500 page, if I want to view the actual error message I have to go into /var/log and cat the actual error log. This is quite annoying to do in development all the time.

I know that one can have errors show up on the web page, but this is not always convenient either when working with JSON etc and it messes up the page.

I know that with most python framework for example , error messages are just printed to stdout when the server application is run, however in this case since I am just attaching PHP to the apache service background process I don't see how that would be possible.

Is there some way to view the error logs in real time in a window with apache?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: +1. `-f` being the "follow" - dump the last 10 lines of the file, then keep dumping any new lines as they're added to the file.

Comment: For those who are on Windows, try [Tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yeah, I never knew until just now that edits have to be at least 6 characters. That seems arbitrary to me but I'm sure there is a huge meta thread about it. *slowly disappears into the meta black hole*

Answer (score 7):

In real time use:

```
sudo watch tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```